# How to define default values for parameters for the Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have Swagger/Swashbuckle integrated into a .NET Core 2.2 API project.  Everything works great and what I am asking is purely for convenience.  Consider the following API method:

```
public Model SomeEstimate(SomeRequest request) {
    return Manager.GetSomeEstimate(request);
}
...
public class SomeRequest {
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

When I hit /swagger/index.html and want to try out this API, I always have to enter the StreetAddress and Zip values.

Is there a way to provide default values for StreetAddress and Zip?  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229244) suggested placing [DefaultValue("value here")] attribute each property of the `SomeRequest` class.  It may have worked for the regular .NET, but not with .NET Core.

Is it possible to provide default values for parameters for the Swagger UI?

Comment: See this link: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/575#issuecomment-461962745 .You would have to create a schema filter to achieve the DefaultValue attribute working in .NET Core

Comment: @RahulSharma Excellent, that did the trick!

Comment: @RahulSharma Do it so it's visible to whoever else has this question.

Comment: See my answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528575/swashbuckle-swagger-generate-an-actual-guid/57528916#57528916

Comment: See my answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528575/swashbuckle-swagger-generate-an-actual-guid/57528916#57528916

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To define default values for parameters for Swagger UI in .NET Core, the following [article](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/575#issuecomment-461962745) defines a custom schema filter for your DefaultValue attribute in your Model class. The code shown below has been taken from this article and is purely to inform anyone else who has this question or has been facing a similar problem:

Decorate the desired properties in a model:

```
public class Test {
    [DefaultValue("Hello")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Main filter:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace Project.Swashbuckle {

    public class SchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter {

        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context) {
            if (schema.Properties == null) {
                return;
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in context.SystemType.GetProperties()) {

                // Look for class attributes that have been decorated with "[DefaultAttribute(...)]".
                DefaultValueAttribute defaultAttribute = propertyInfo
                    .GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>();

                if (defaultAttribute != null) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Schema> property in schema.Properties) {

                        // Only assign default value to the proper element.
                        if (ToCamelCase(propertyInfo.Name) == property.Key) {
                            property.Value.Example = defaultAttribute.Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private string ToCamelCase(string name) {
            return char.ToLowerInvariant(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally registering it to your Swagger Options(In Startup.cs):

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    // ...
    c.SchemaFilter<SchemaFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to provide default values for [parameters with FromQuery attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065200/how-to-define-default-values-for-fromquery-parameters-for-the-swagger-ui)?

Comment: @AngryHacker See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375960/how-to-set-two-default-fields-to-my-input-model-on-asp-net-webapi-net-core#comment97496730_55375960

Answer (score 10):

The initial credit goes to [Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052232/1740719), though if someone is interested in .NET Core 3.0+, Swashbuckle v5.0.0-rc4 makes the *SchemaFilter* definition much simpler. Maybe there's a way to add example value with a new attribute or something like that, but I haven't found such a way.

```
public class SchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Value.Default != null && property.Value.Example == null)
            {
                property.Value.Example = property.Value.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3 needs just `DefaultValueAttribute`.

Comment: Implemented here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/575

Answer (score 3):

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3 needs just `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute` like so:

```cs
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue((int)DateTypeEnum.CreationDate)]
public int DateType{ get; set; }
```

For reference type properties like `datetime` type,  you cannot use the `System.ComponentModelDefaultValueAttribute` since it does not support a reference type initialize.
For this case I created a custom default value attribute that get a string value and convert it to a primitive type. then I defined a schema filter that set the value into the default `memberInfo` schema:

1. **DefaultValueAttribute**

```
  public class DefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public IOpenApiPrimitive Value { get; set; }


        public DefaultValueAttribute(PrimitiveType type, string value = "")
        {
            SetValue(type, value);
        }

        public DefaultValueAttribute(PrimitiveType type = PrimitiveType.DateTime, int addYears = 0, int addDays = 0, int addMonths = 0)
        {
            SetValue(type, "", addYears, addDays, addMonths);
        }

        private void SetValue(PrimitiveType Type, string value = "", int addYears = 0, int addDays = 0, int addMonths = 0)
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
                case PrimitiveType.Integer:
                    Value = new OpenApiInteger(Convert.ToInt32(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Long:
                    Value = new OpenApiLong(Convert.ToInt64(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Float:
                    Value = new OpenApiFloat(Convert.ToUInt64(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Double:
                    Value = new OpenApiDouble(Convert.ToDouble(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.String:
                    Value = new OpenApiString(value);
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Byte:
                    Value = new OpenApiByte(Convert.ToByte(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Binary:
                    Value = new OpenApiBinary(value.ToCharArray().Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c)).ToArray());
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Boolean:
                    Value = new OpenApiBoolean(Convert.ToBoolean(value));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Date:
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.DateTime:
                    Value = new OpenApiDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(addYears).AddDays(addDays).AddMonths(addMonths));
                    break;
                case PrimitiveType.Password:
                    Value = new OpenApiPassword(value);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

2. **SchemaFilter**

```cs
 public class DefaultValuesSwaggerExtensions : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            var attributes = context?.MemberInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>();

            if (attributes?.Any() == true)
            {
                schema.Default = attributes.First().Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

3. **Add the filter to Swagger**

```cs
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SchemaFilter<DefaultValuesSwaggerExtensions>();
            });
```

4. **add the attribute to the property**

```cs
 [DTOs.Common.DefaultValue(Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.PrimitiveType.DateTime, -1)]
  public DateTime FromDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For value types you can use just `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute` like so:

```cs
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue((int)DateTypeEnum.CreationDate)]
public int DateType{ get; set; }
```

For primitive type property like `datetime` type,  you cannot add a default value in the `System.ComponentModelDefaultValueAttribute` since attribute does not support a reference type initialize.
For this case I created a custom default value attribute that get a string value and convert it to a primitive type. then I defined a schema filter that set the value into the default `memberInfo` schema:

1. **DefaultValueAttribute**

```
public class DefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IOpenApiPrimitive Value { get; set; }

    public DefaultValueAttribute(PrimitiveType type, string value = "")
    {
        SetValue(type, value);
    }

    public DefaultValueAttribute(PrimitiveType type = PrimitiveType.DateTime, int addYears = 0, int addDays = 0, int addMonths = 0)
    {
        SetValue(type, "", addYears, addDays, addMonths);
    }

    private void SetValue(PrimitiveType Type, string value = "", int addYears = 0, int addDays = 0, int addMonths = 0)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case PrimitiveType.Integer:
                Value = new OpenApiInteger(Convert.ToInt32(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Long:
                Value = new OpenApiLong(Convert.ToInt64(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Float:
                Value = new OpenApiFloat(Convert.ToUInt64(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Double:
                Value = new OpenApiDouble(Convert.ToDouble(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.String:
                Value = new OpenApiString(value);
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Byte:
                Value = new OpenApiByte(Convert.ToByte(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Binary:
                Value = new OpenApiBinary(value.ToCharArray().Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c)).ToArray());
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Boolean:
                Value = new OpenApiBoolean(Convert.ToBoolean(value));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Date:
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.DateTime:
                Value = new OpenApiDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(addYears).AddDays(addDays).AddMonths(addMonths));
                break;
            case PrimitiveType.Password:
                Value = new OpenApiPassword(value);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

2. **SchemaFilter**

```cs
public class DefaultValuesSwaggerExtensions : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var attributes = context?.MemberInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>();

        if (attributes?.Any() == true)
        {
            schema.Default = attributes.First().Value;
        }
    }
}
```

3. **Add the filter to Swagger**

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
         c.SchemaFilter<DefaultValuesSwaggerExtensions>();
    });
```

4. **use the attribute on the property**

```cs
[DTOs.Common.DefaultValue(Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.PrimitiveType.DateTime, -1)]
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To have default values for swagger you can simply register a custom schemaFilter:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValue>();
    });
}
```

That schema filter analysed a certain attribute for default values:

```
public class SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValue : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ParameterInfo != null)
        {
            var att = context.ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute>();
            if (att != null)
            {
                schema.Example = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString(att.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This attribute looks like this:

```
public class SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

So you simply need to add this attribute to the properties of you classes:

```
public class SomeRequest 
{
    [SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValue("Teststreet")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValue("74821")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

In every case you will add an OpenApiString but it will be converted to the certain property type when displayed in swagger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
public class ExternalJobCreateViewModel
{
    ///<example>Bob</example>
    public string CustomFilename { get; set; }

    ///<example>false</example>
    public bool IsUrgent { get; set; }

    ///<example>false</example>
    public bool IsMultiSpeaker { get; set; }

    ///<example></example>
    public string JobInstruction { get; set; }

    ///<example></example>
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).