# How to set two default fields to my input-model on ASP .Net webAPi .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a base class that I call InputModelBase the idea with this one is that all REST post APIs shall use this base class for Input models.

I have two default properties on this one: UserId and TestParams

What I want to do is a middleware or something that check if my parameter is of type InputModelBase if so I want to bind a Iprinciple claim Userid to the userid property, and also TestParam if there are some values defined in the header.

I tried to build my own binding provider but got lost. 
I do not want to take ownership of the standard way of bind things. So I just want to use my already binded model and just add two values to it.

I want this in a middleware so devs do not need to add them by hand in all our REST Apis.

When they use the inputmodel the userID shall be there and also testparams if sent by the header.

So somehow I need to hook in when the binding is done and just before it pass me to the controller method it self

Comment: You want to have DefaultValues for your `UserId` and `TestParams` when your API is called ?

Comment: Yes. When a user Post data to let say /api/v1/user and I have a FromBody UserIntPutModel I want it to bind as is does by default. But I want to add use two default fields on all my input models that add userid and testparam to this inputmodel. Instead of ask for my claim for userid all the time.

Comment: No it does not...

Answer (score 1):

I made it with Middleware of Filter actions. I tried the wrong filer options. My bad.

```
public class DefaultCommandSettingsActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var command = context.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x is ICommand);

        if(command != null)
            ((dynamic)command).TestHarness = "Set values here!";

        await next();
    }
}
```