# How to define default values for [FromQuery] parameters for the Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("foo")]
public ActionResult Foo([FromQuery] MyClass request)
{
    var image = ToImage(WidgetType.MedianSalesPriceSqft, request);
    return File(image.ToByteArray(), "image/png");
}
```

below  MyClass is defined:

```
public class MyClass {
    [DefaultValue("90210")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("5361 Doverton Dr")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }               
}
```

When I hit /swagger/index.html and want to try out this API, I always have to enter the StreetAddress and Zip values, even though I have default values defined.

Swagger currently provides a [schema filter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/575#issuecomment-461962745) that let's you provide default values for object properties as long as they are not set to be [FromQuery].  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: What version of swashbuckle are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem has been fixed on the beta version:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/5.0.0-rc2

*Lot of changes on the beta version, I had a couple of DocumentFilter and needed to be refactored,

I had to comment some stuff out that could not figure out how to do on the beta.*

I added your same action and class, it looks like this:

[image]

Once you click on the try it out the values are populated
[image]

Just if you needed my code is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/tree/master/WebApi_NetCore

Comment: I see.  I can't upgrade to an RC - gotta release in the next 3 weeks.  Will have to wait a bit and upgrade later.  Thank you.

Comment: @AngryHacker there is absolutely no reason not to use the RC, If you are concerned with bugs remember you are using opensource software, the amount of reported issues might scare you: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues