# Swashbuckle Swagger generate an actual guid

Tags: c#, swagger, guid, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger in my .Net Core WebAPI project. As you can see below, it generates a GUID of type string. I would like to generate a random Guid and replace "string" with "" or an empty guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". This would allow my example to actually work when I post it.

```
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "GUID": "string",
      "status": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

while I am at it, would it be possible to the same with any string so that JSON is different each time?

Comment: How is the `GUID` property defined in your C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorate your GUID property in your payload class like this

```
public class Payload
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The GUID
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</example>
    public string Guid { get; set; }
}
```

This should change the example from "string" to "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

EDIT: Forgot to add. In your startup.cs you might need to add the following code

```
        // Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "TEST API", Version = "v1" });

            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, you can use DefaultValue attribute.
Ex:

```
[DefaultValue("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]
public string Guid { get; set; }
```

It has been implemented recently: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/575

Comment: how to add example to a route based input param ? 
 /// <summary>
        /// Get basket based on id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">should be guid / uuid format</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("{id}")]
        [SwaggerOperation("BasketGetById")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(BasketModel))]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
        public IHttpActionResult GetById(string id)