# NetCore: How to provide SwaggerUI with an example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

When I have set up a `Controller` function with netcore6 like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(nameof(UpdateMaterialCalculationConfiguration))]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(EditorResponse<EditorMaterialCalculationConfigurationResponse>))]
public IActionResult UpdateMaterialCalculationConfiguration([Required][FromBody] EditorUpdateMaterialCalculationConfigurationRequest request)
{
  ...
}
```

The Swagger UI will provide you with a basic `json` with the names of the properties and their datatype, like this:

```
{
  "MaterialId": "string",
  "MaterialType": "string",
  ...
}
```

But is it possible to describe - in `C#` - a specific example?

Comment: Is this what you want? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210087/swagger-default-value-for-parameter

Comment: follow sample project https://github.com/upendarreddy678/SwaggerUI-Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating XML File for the Project and add it to swagger it will help you generating swagger Documentation. Follow below steeps
Step:1 Suppose your Project is `TestAPI` add below lines to `TestAPI.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <DocumentationFile>TestAPI.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After saving you will get `TestAPI.xml` file in your project directory.

Step:2 configure `builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen()` as below. it will add `TestAPI.xml` file to your swagger documentation

```
 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  {
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    if (File.Exists(xmlFile))
    {
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
    }
 });
```

what ever written in `summary` will give you as shown in below

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test Service is used To 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"> key of The Record </param>
    /// <response code="200">On Successfull Request</response>
    [HttpGet("TestServe")]
    public IActionResult TestServe(string id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

[image]

step:3 decorate property with example as shown in below it modify the json value with example value.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// To Create Test
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Inp">Sample Request</param>
    /// <response code="200">On Successfull Create</response>
    [HttpPost("TestCreate")]
    public IActionResult TestCreate(MyTestClass Inp)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public class MyTestClass
    {
        /// <example>1</example>
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <example>Upender</example>
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

follow [SampleProject](https://github.com/upendarreddy678/SwaggerUI-Example)

Comment: In Visual studio press `///` it will automatically generate sample `Summary`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend SwaggerUI with some request example, you can use XML comments for your method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an Employee.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Sample request:
/// 
///     POST api/Employee
///     {        
///       "firstName": "Mike",
///       "lastName": "Andrew",
///       "emailId": "Mike.Andrew@gmail.com"        
///     }
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="employee"></param>
```

Be aware about XML warnings.
More details can be found here:
https://code-maze.com/swagger-ui-asp-net-core-web-api/

But if you want to provide a RESPONSE example, you better to youse the OPEN-API approach for your .Net core application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Open-api will give you the possibility to control your request\response contracts fully (HTTP code, Body payload, headers, Error messages and etc.)